# Dlls to access Notes and Domino Server Database

Tags: c#, lotus-domino, interop-domino

I need to create an application using C# such that i can access all the user's mailboxes existing on Server.

So kindly provide me the API which will allow me to access each mailbox( nsf files) of each user stored on the Domino Server.

Basically i am looking for an API by which i can just provide the Domino Server name through which i can get all mailboxes.

Comment: We are not here to sell APIs ;-)

Comment: Sorry to say Sir.
But you didn't understand my question.

Anyway..thanx for reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the dll you are looking for is nnotes.dll.  If you have lotus notes installed visual studio should pick it up automatically for you to add in your references.

All the documentation for the api is here --> http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/uafiles.nsf/docs/DESIGNER70/$File/prog2.pdf